# Почему в строке level пишется true вместо значения

Tags: laravel

При создании авторизованного пользователя `$admin = auth()->user();` заносятся данные все корректно кроме поля `level` в БД в этом поле `admin`, а не true

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

через `dd()` в `attributes` `"level" => true` а в `original` правильное значение `"level" => "admin"` можно как то из `original` взять это значение или как узнать почему оно поменялось в `attributes` любым советам буду рад

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если что я решил это костылём полумерой но найти ответ был бы не прочь вот мой костыль:

```
        $admin = Auth::user();
        $NowAdmin = User::where('id', $admin['id'])->first();
        if($NowAdmin->level === 'admin'){
            if ($user->level === 'admin'){
                return redirect(route('OpenAllUsers'))->withErrors([
                    'AdminErrorDelete' => 'Обычный админ не может удалять себеподобных!',
                ]);
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```

Comment: покажите код модели User

Comment: @DmitriiSedov
добавил к вопросу) пробовал добавлять менять fillable и hidden толку нет

Comment: `Attributes` это измененный данные, как будто вы где-то указали `$admin->level = true`. Как ещё вариант, можно воспользоваться `$admin->getOriginal('level')`